# angular2 cordova android failing to run in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, angular

I setup a basic `angular2` app in cordova, it runs fine in iOS but with android I'm getting build failed with an exception, I can run android fine in a basic cordova app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Error: /Users/username/Code/workshop/cordova/angular-2/MyApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: i'm wondering if it has something to do with the avd not having enough resources to launch, maybe if i increase available ram, vm heap.

Answer (score 0):

ok i resolved the issue which was caused by node_modules folder being too heavy for the emulator to launch, i cut a lot of fat from node_modules (i.e deleted dependencies and other fluff that wasn't needed) and increased the resources available to the avd.

things ran smooth after that :)